# When pass multiple parameters onclick event not working. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

The button create dynamically having `onclick` event, it working fine when I pass a single reference variable **this**, but at the time when I pass multiple parameters by `onclick` event, it is not working. Guide me on what I am doing wrong? I tried the following code:

**Button Create script**

```
$(document).on('change','.typeOption',function(){
    labelVal=$(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();
    console.log(labelVal);
    if($(this).val() == 'radio' || $(this).val() == 'select'){
        $(this).closest('tr').after("<button type='button' class='btn btn-block createOptionBtn' onclick='createOptions(this,'"+labelVal+"')'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i> Add Option</button>");
    }
});
```

Pass value to this function:

```
function createOptions(e,myval){
    $(e).parent().parent().find('.row').show();
    console.log(myval);
    $(e).parent().parent().find('.row').append('<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px">'+
            '<div class="input-group">'+
              '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter option..." >'+
              '<span class="input-group-addon" onclick="removeOption(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span>'+
            '</div>'+
      '</div>');
}
```

Comment: Any error in your browse console regarding this (button creation and then click on button)

Comment: post the rest of HTML as well :|

Comment: @AlivetoDie no error display at the time of creating button or click

Comment: When i pass the second parameter, Add button not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes escaping issue on button creation.

Do like below:-

```
$(this).closest('tr').after('<button type"button" class="btn btn-block createOptionBtn" onclick="createOptions(this,\'' + labelVal + '\')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Option</button>');
```

Demo example (just to show that it worked):-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  labelVal='abc';
  $('div').append('<button type"button" class="btn btn-block createOptionBtn" onclick="createOptions(this,\'' + labelVal + '\')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Option</button>');
});
function createOptions(e,myval){
    $(e).after('<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-bottom:10px"><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter option..." ><span class="input-group-addon" onclick="removeOption(this)">remove<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span></div></div>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: When i pass the second parameter, Add option button not working

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick` abc is the input text given by me. and after click on button this error shown

Comment: @JayZamsol  can you once check my edited answer. Yes my code have an issue and i resolved it

Comment: @JayZamsol  glad to help you. Thanks